# D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile linker error

Tags: c++, linker, textures, linker-errors, directx-11

I am working on a directX 11 project, and I came across a strange linking error.
The function D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile throws a LNK2019 error.

Is there a library I'm missing? I can get to the declaration in d3d11tex.h, but the program does not find the implementation.

What am I missing? It seems I have included and referenced everything I needed to... besides, as I mentioned, I can reach the declaration.

**The error:**

Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFileW@24 referenced in function "public: __thiscall Texture2d::Texture2d(struct ID3D11Device *,wchar_t *)" (??0Texture2d@@QAE@PAUID3D11Device@@PA_W@Z) Z:\Year 4\Coursework\Coursework\Coursework\Texture2d.obj    Coursework

**Here is the code (.cpp), with the includes:**

```
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <d3dx11.h>

Texture2d::Texture2d(ID3D11Device* device, WCHAR* fileName)
{
    D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile(device, fileName, NULL, NULL, &m_texture, NULL);
}
```

**Library directory:**
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Lib\x86

**Include directories:**
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Samples\C++\Effects11\Inc

**EDIT!**
I forgot to show my library links, but someone came up with a solution without even looking at it. Indeed, it was missing d3dx11.lib.

```
#pragma comment(lib, "d3d11.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "d3dcompiler.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "dxerr.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Effects11.lib")
```

Comment: Add D3DX11.lib to the linker list.

Comment: Thank you! I had d3d11 included to the project, but not d3dx11. I assumed one included the other.

Comment: @AlexFarber You may want to remove the comment and convert to an answer...

Comment: It's be a better idea to set the libraries in your project's linker settings instead of listing them in the source code using a `#pragma`.